# Retrieving page contents from SQL, Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, data-pages

Data is stored [over pages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/storage-page-layout.html#AEN119524) and not necessarily one row or one column or one attribute maps to one page. Is it possible to use some query to extract data from a specific page in a database environment?

Comment: Are you asking for SQL Server as well as Postgres?

Comment: No, I am interested to see if postgresql can offer this interaction maybe through some extension as pageinspect

Answer (score 1):

## [`pageinspect` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pageinspect.html)

Using PostgreSQL, there is an extension that does all of this. Your question is vague so I won't even try to address the particulars here, nor is it reasonable to enumerate everything this extension does, perhaps it's enough to say that it has 17 functions and as far as I know includes *all* of the mechanisms available to end users to introspect pages (not saying it does everything you want).

You may want to read [*Database Page Layout*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/storage-page-layout.html)

Comment: Thanks, that extension is close to what I'm looking for: I would like to see contents of pages. Something which is odd though is that there does not seem to be any functions for working with GiST index - why?